# Ubuntu 16.04 ISO image is not bootable

Tags: iso

I need a bootable DVD to install a desktop from scratch. The default 16.04 distribution .iso is not bootable. Where could I find an bootable image that has files shown in following web page?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD

Comment: the default Ubuntu 16.04LTS [iso] is bootable; I still often use dvd's to install.  Before writing it you verify the download worked (ie. md5sum matched what it should have been, no mitm attack or just bad download) then you write it (expand [growisofs] & write) to dvd correctly, otherwise you'll just get a data-dvd containing the ISO.  If you didn't expand-during-write you've probably just written the iso on a data-dvd.   (many gui, or cli tools will do this; but I don't know what you use/used; but it needs to know you want iso image bootable & not just dat-backup image)

Comment: Why won't it boot? (that's probably a better question)

Comment: Please see my comments below. The burned DVD does not have setup.exe etc. It only has md5sum.txt, readme.diskdefines and 10 folders. That's why I question if this is correct ISO image.

Answer (score 1):

An Ubuntu installation ISO contains everything that is needed for booting
on old BIOS firmware and on modern EFI firmware. You just need to burn it
as "image" to the DVD, not as "data project" where you could compose a
DVD from more than one file.

If you already have a GNU/Linux system with DVD burner, you may use Xfburn,
K3B, or Brasero which all offer image burning (which you want) and data
project burning (which you don't want).

On the shell command line, it would be

```
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/sr0=ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso
```

or

```
xorriso -as cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 blank=as_needed -eject ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso
```

If you only have a MS-Windows system for burning, then look for instructions
like in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd451080.aspx

You may also put the ISO flatly onto an USB stick. (Again, not as file into
a filesystem but as filesystem image.) For GNU/Linux instructions see
http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid#Copying_onto_USB_stick_by_shell_commands .
With MS-Windows consider programs "win32diskimager" or "Rufus" in its "dd"
mode (not in its file unpacking mode).

Comment: I have good experience of burning an iso file to a DVD disk with **`k3b`**

Comment: I don't have a Linux system. That is what I'm trying to install. I could only burn DVD from a Windows system. I followed the instruction (like your link) to burn it. However the resulting DVD only as a checksum file and a Readme.* file in addition to the folders. There is no setup.exe and other files shown in the web page I listed in my OP. So I'm question if I get the correct ISO image.

Comment: The 16.10 ISO i have bears only two data files: "README.diskdefines" and
"md5sum.txt". Plus 10 directories from ".disk" to "preseed".
So the DVD seems to be ok now. The screenshots are from year 2006:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD?action=info

Comment: But this DVD is not bootable when I insert it into a desktop that does not have an OS installed.

Comment: Does it boot from other bootable DVDs ?

Comment: Yes. I have a 15 years old Fedora disk. It still could boot. However it does not have the drivers for my system.

Comment: The old ISO can only have equipment for BIOS, not for EFI. If your firmware
is EFI then it seems to have fallen back to BIOS Legacy mode. Can you set your
firmware explicitely to BIOS Legcay mode and try Ubuntu again ?

Comment: How do I set my firmware? I don't see any instructions about this.

Comment: It seems manufacturer dependent. Dell proposes to press F2 Key when
their logo appears. There is supposed to be a setup utility for the 
firmware with settings like "Secure Boot" (try "off") and "Boot Mode" 
with ("Legacy" and "UEFI"). We should continue to explore this by
mail in private. Mine is: scdbackup@gmx.net

Comment: This is a system I built myself 4 years ago. Now its HD failed and I decided to get a new HD and put a Linux on it instead of Windows.